# Ограничить возможный размер текста

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Вводится текст в EditText, он автоматически уменьшается. Сейчас это происходит почти бесконечно, мне же нужно чтобы когда текст достиг лимита, который еще задается мною, возможность продолжить ввод была недоступна.
В общем, мне необходимо понять как задать этот минимальный раз, и как реализовать прекращение ввода при достижении лимита.

Comment: android:maxLength="10" пробовали?

Comment: да, но у разных символов разная ширина,  и поэтому  это ограничение не совсем корректно

Answer (score 0):

Вводимый текст в EditText можно ограничить лишь параметром android:maxLength, который вам уже посоветовали. Могу лишь посоветовать еще поиграться с android:textSize в паре с предыдущим параметром для достижения оптимального результата. А то, что вам нужно - навскидку могу сказать, что можно на EditText повесить TextWatcher с помощью метода addTextChangedListener() и там уже играться с получением длины EditText + длины введенного текста(хотя мне правда интересно как вы собрались такую динамически меняющуюся вещь, как реальная длина строки в dp, привязать к длине EditText). Может я что-то и упускаю, но если еще кто-нибудь знает, то подскажут.